# How to build a search bar in a list flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

i'm a beginner in flutter and i need your help.
i want to create a search bar with the name of the users but i don't really know how to do it.
The goal is that a user can search other users name in this search bar.

please help me
here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:app/models/chatparams.dart';


class UserList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListState createState() => _UserListState();
}

class _UserListState extends State<UserList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final users = Provider.of<List<AppUserData>>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: users.length ,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return UserTile(users[index ]);
      
        });
      

}
}



class UserTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final AppUserData user;

  UserTile(this.user);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final currentUser = Provider.of<AppUser?>(context);
    if (currentUser == null) throw Exception("current user not found");

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (currentUser.uid == user.uid) return;
        Navigator.pushNamed(
          context,
          '/chat',
          arguments: ChatParams(currentUser.uid, user),
        );
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        child: Card(
          margin:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.profilepic),
            ),
            title: Text(user.name),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can wrap `ListView.builder` with ListView/column and handle searchBar there by filtering the list.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://medium.com/codechai/implementing-search-in-flutter-17dc5aa72018 An example using SearchDelegate

Comment: sorry but i couldn't because UserTile  and Listuser are in different classes                               do you have a solution?